# Firebase custom domain doesn't survive App Store installation iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm having an issue getting my React Native iOS app Firebase Dynamic Link to survive the App Store installation process.  This link works fine when the app is installation and works perfectly in Android.  Dynamic Link urls also work perfectly with Google branded urls such as page.link or goo.gl.

I created a couple of custom domains, properly set the custom url, associated domains, and added them to the FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains array in the plist and still can't get them to work from an app store launch.  I also added some logs to the AppDelegate file to see if the url is getting lost somewhere, but I don't see it coming in the native iOS code. I do, however, see the dynamic links showing up when the app is installed and or I use a Google branded domain like page.link.  I also tested my domains with Firebase's quickstart app and they don't work unless the app is installed.
The custom domain does work when the app preview screen is enabled, but I would prefer not to use it see there's a branded interstitial page that redirects the user to the App Store if the app isn't installed.

I am using react-native-firebase/analytics 11.1.2, react-native-firebase/app 11.1.2, react-native-firebase/dynamic-links 11.1.2, and react-native-firebase/messaging 11.1.2.  I don't know if this is a third party issue or a Firebase SDK issue.

I'm testing for the presence of the url in the native and React code here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:
#if defined(__IPHONE_12_0) && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_12_0)
(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#else
    (nonnull void (^)(NSArray *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#endif  // __IPHONE_12_0
  BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL
                                                          completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink,
                                                                       NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (dynamicLink.url) {
      NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Foreground deep link iOS native %@", dynamicLink.url.absoluteString];
      [SentrySDK captureMessage:message];
    } else {
      [SentrySDK captureMessage:@"Foreground deep link iOS native no deep link found"];
    }
                                                          }];
  return handled;
}
```

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
              openURL:(NSURL *)url
              options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {
    return [self application:app
                     openURL:url
           sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                  annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  }

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
              openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
           annotation:(id)annotation {
    FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];

    if (dynamicLink) {
      if (dynamicLink.url) {
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Background deep link iOS native %@", dynamicLink.url.absoluteString];
        [SentrySDK captureMessage:message];
      } else {
        [SentrySDK captureMessage:@"Background deep link iOS native no deep link found"];
      }
      return YES;
    }
    return NO;
  }
```

And testing for the url in the React code in the App.js file:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dynamicLinks()
      .getInitialLink()
      .then((link) => {
        const deepLink = link ?? 'no deep link available';
        logSentryMessage(JSON.stringify(deepLink), 'Deep link from background');
        if (isNil(link) || isNil(link.url)) {
          return;
        }
        setUrl(link.url);
      });
  }, []);

  /**
   * AppLink handler
   *
   * @param link
   */
  const handleDynamicLink = useCallback(
    (link: FirebaseDynamicLinksTypes.DynamicLink) => {
      const deepLink = link ?? 'no deep link available';
      logSentryMessage(JSON.stringify(deepLink), 'Deep link from foreground');
      if (isNil(link.url)) {
        return;
      }
      setUrl(link.url);
    },
    [],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [handleDynamicLink]);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant code as text.

Comment: Do not post codes as images. Try to include them as code snippets.